# Align both vertically and horizontally using Bootstrap flex

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

After looking through the bootstrap 4 Flex doc, I can't seem to get the "align-item-center" property to work. I tested pretty much every example available online but really can't seem to change the vertical alignment of anything, it's driving me nuts. I join a simple HTML example I'm trying to make work.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
}

.justify-content-center {
  -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
}

.align-items-center {
  -ms-flex-align: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <p> This should be centered right ?</p>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4.4.1 and also have installed popper.js@latest and jquery@latest just to be sure. For further precision I'm only using a simple textline now but in the future I'll add elements whose size are not known until runtime.

Comment: In what way is this **not** centered?

Comment: Its already working. Try to give a height for the parent div and see the alignment.

Answer (score -2):

Set `height` to parent to the screen size or whatever you want i set it to `100%` of view-port height

```
.d-flex.justify-content-center.align-items-center {
    height: 100vh;
}
```